# Flutter and java sdk

Tags: flutter

i've reached a brickwall with java.

```
$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
/Users/simonhampton/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
$ /Users/simonhampton/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
```

I have

```
$ java --version
java 12.0.2 2019-07-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I feel like I've installed everything possible - jre, jdk, dfk, openadk,....and nothing works. Is there a guaranteed solution to make java work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with java 8 SDK or versions before it, Not after this version.